# MESSAGE_DELIVERED events in BigQuery export from firebase not showing

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging

All our notification are sent as `DATA_MESSAGES` using the admin SDK.

I'm trying to ingest the firebase logs to deduce push deliverability.

Here's what I have done so far

- Linked Firebase project to BigQuery
- Turned on BigQuery export ( I can see `firebase_messaging` table and can query it)
- In the `AndroidManifest` added

```
 <meta-data android:name="delivery_metrics_exported_to_big_query_enabled"
                   android:value="true"/>
```

I dont see any events with the value `event = 'MESSAGE_DELIVERED'` in the exported table in Big Query
Am I missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of FCM SDK are you using ? Have you allowed some days to check the events ? Because some delay may occur.

Comment: Realised I was on an old version of the SDK. Upgrading to 20.1.5. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: After upgrading to the newest version of the SDK, can you check if there are events with 'MESSAGE DELIVERED'? Please allow some to check in case some delay happens.